# How to give source : path to jQuery autocomplete from Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, sql, codeigniter

I have used jQuery auto complete on my Codeigniter application. But it's not working due to source path is broken.

This is my code:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('.zipsearch').autocomplete({
                source:'jQueryAutocompleteRelatedFields.php', 
                minLength:2,
                select:function(evt, ui)
                {
                    // when a zipcode is selected, populate related fields in this form
                    this.form.city.value = ui.item.city;
                    this.form.state.value = ui.item.state;
                }
            });
        });
```

Currently file jQueryAutocompleteRelatedFields.php is on the following file path:

> www\CI\application\views\search\jQueryAutocompleteRelatedFields.php
>
> localhost\CI\index.php\search\searchItem

Is my browser path

How can I give the source?

---

SearchITem is function which coming under search controller,

Update : jQueryAutocompleteRelatedFields.php

```
     <?php

class DB
{
    const DATABASE = 'inventory';
    const HOST = '127.0.0.1';
    const USERNAME = 'root';
    const PASSWORD = '';

    static private $pdo;

    static public function singleton()
    {
        if (!is_object(self::$pdo))
        {
            self::$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . self::DATABASE . ';host=' . self::HOST, 
                                    self::USERNAME, 
                                    self::PASSWORD);
        }
        return self::$pdo;
    }

    private function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function __clone()
    {
        throw new Exception('You may not clone the DB instance');
    }
}

if (!isset($_REQUEST['term']))
{
    die('([])');
}

$st = DB::singleton()
        ->prepare(
            'select product_id, product_code, product_name ' .
            'from tbl_product ' .
            'where product_id like :product_id ' .
            'order by product_id asc ' .
            'limit 0,10');

$searchZip = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';
$st->bindParam(':product_id', $searchZip, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$data = array();
if ($st->execute())
{
    while ($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'value' => $row->product_id ,
            'city' => $row->product_code ,
            'state' => $row->product_name
        );
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the browser path with forward slashes.

```
source: 'localhost/CI/index.php/search/searchitem',
```

You will have an issue moving this to a real web server though because you will want to use a relative path. I highly recommend setting up your local environment to be as similar as possible to the web server.

EDIT:

In CodeIgniter add the following code to your Search controller:

```
public function fetchList(){

    // I assume your view is outputting an array ready to be encoded with JSON?
    return json_encode($this->load->view('search/jQueryAutocompleteRelatedFields.php', array(), true));

    // Try this if the code above doesn't work
    return json_encode(array('item1','item2','item3','item4'));

}
```

Now point the AJAX source like this:

```
source: 'localhost/CI/index.php/search/fetchList',
```

Comment: so do i have to replace  source:'jQueryAutocompleteRelatedFields.php' with the above mention path...then how does the url point to jQueryAutocompleteRelatedFields.php file ?

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood what you meant be browser path. Since you are using CodeIgniter you will need to modify some things in your controller. I will update my post

Comment: i have update my question with 'jQueryAutocompleteRelatedFields.php file .. do i have to add those details to my model or controller ?

Comment: I'm sorry but this post is going WAY outside of the scope of your original question. The best advice I can give you is to re-evaluate your MVC structure because your view "jQueryAutocompleteRelatedFields.php" should not look like that. Please read my EDIT: because I specified Search controller. Also you should use return json_encode(array('item1','item2','item3','item4')); until you get a better understanding of the situation.

Comment: You should start here learning CodeIgniter here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/